# Perceptron with Stochastic Gradient Descent - why is the training algorithm degrading with iteration?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, perceptron

I am implementing my own perceptron algorithm in python wihtout using numpy or scikit yet. I wanted to get the basics right before proceeding to machine learning specific modules.

I wrote the code as given below.

1. used iris data set to classify based on sepal length and petal size.
2. updating the weights at the end of each training set
3. learning rate, number of iterations for training provided to the algorithm from client

Issues:

My training algorithm degrades instead of improving over time. Can someone please explain what i am doing incorrectly.

This is my error set across iteration number, as you can see the error is actually increasing.

{
0: 0.01646885885483229, 
1: 0.017375368112097056, 
2: 0.018105024923841584, 
3: 0.01869233173693685, 
4: 0.019165059856726563, 
5: 0.01954556263697238, 
6: 0.019851832477317588, 
7: 0.02009835160930562, 
8: 0.02029677690109266, 
9: 0.020456491062436744
}

```
import pandas as panda
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot 
import random

remote_location = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'

class Perceptron(object):

    def __init__(self, epochs, learning_rate, weight_range = None):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.weight_range = weight_range if weight_range else [-1, 1]
        self.weights = []
        self._x_training_set = None
        self._y_training_set = None
        self.number_of_training_set = 0        

    def setup(self):

        self.number_of_training_set = self.setup_training_set()
        self.initialize_weights(len(self._x_training_set[0]) + 1)

    def setup_training_set(self):
        """

        Downloading training set data from UCI ML Repository - Iris DataSet

        """

        data = panda.read_csv(remote_location)       

        self._x_training_set = list(data.iloc[0:, [0,2]].values)
        self._y_training_set = [0 if i.lower()!='iris-setosa' else 1 
                                    for i in data.iloc[0:, 4].values]

        return len(self._x_training_set)

    def initialize_weights(self, number_of_weights):
        random_weights = [random.uniform(self.weight_range[0], self.weight_range[1]) 
                                for i in range(number_of_weights)]
        self.weights.append(-1) # setting up bias unit 
        self.weights.extend(random_weights)

    def draw_initial_plot(self, _x_data, _y_data, _x_label, _y_label):

        plot.xlabel(_x_label)
        plot.ylabel(_y_label)
        plot.scatter(_x_data,_y_data)
        plot.show()

    def learn(self):

        self.setup() 
        epoch_data = {}
        error = 0

        for epoch in range(self.epochs):

            for i in range(self.number_of_training_set):
                _x = self._x_training_set[i]
                _desired = self._y_training_set[i]
                _weight = self.weights
                guess = _weight[0] ## setting up the bias unit

                for j in range(len(_x)):
                    guess += _weight[j+1] * _x[j]

                error = _desired - guess

                ## i am going to reset all the weights
                if error!= 0 :

                    ## resetting the bias unit
                    self.weights[0] = error * self.learning_rate

                    for j in range(len(_x)):
                        self.weights[j+1] = self.weights[j+1] + error * self.learning_rate * _x[j]

            #saving error at the end of the training set        
            epoch_data[epoch] = error

        # print(epoch_data)

        self.draw_initial_plot(list(epoch_data.keys()), list(epoch_data.values()),'Epochs', 'Error')

def runMyCode():
    learning_rate = 0.01
    epochs = 15
    random_generator_start = -1
    random_generator_end = 1
    perceptron = Perceptron(epochs, learning_rate, [random_generator_start, random_generator_end])
    perceptron.learn()

runMyCode()
```

plot with epoch 6 
[image]

plot with epoch > 6

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Really is weird, since I just ran your code (as is) and got the following plot:

[image]

Can you elaborate on where you see this error? maybe you are reading it in reverse.

Comment: hey, thank you for ur response. i have been playing around with the above code since posting it here.  i can see that if i keep the epoch to 6, training algorithms tends to converge to error 0. however anything more than that and the algorithm degrades to moving further away from zero error.  i have added the plots to my original answer. since i dont know how to add pics to this particular comment. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the issue. i was plotting the error function incorrectly.

the error in gradient descent is error squared/ so the code should be:

epoch_data[epoch] = error

once i did that, the epoch vs cost function plotting was always coming as converging towards zero, irrespective of the number of epochs.